# `xypic` arrowtip for normal subobjects

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

In `xypic`, I would like to make an arrow tip which resembles the notation for normal subobjects given by `\vartriangleleft`. I would like the arrow to look more or less like the one in the picture below.

How can I make such an arrow?

[image]

Comment: You can see the manual at the link http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/graphics/xyrefer.pdf. Peraphs your symbol can be built con TikZ because it not exist.

Answer (score 1):

One option for typesetting the `\vartriangleleft` symbol in the middle of the arrow is:

```
\[
\xymatrix{A\ar[r]|-{\vartriangleleft} & B}
\]
```

The problem is that the symbol does not rotate with the arrow. In particular, this method won't work for vertical or diagonal arrows.

Answer (score 1):

If the use of a `\xymatrix` is not mandatory for you, here is a solution with `tikz-cd`.

P.S. = thanks to Symbol 1 for his/her solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373836/101651).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\mytri}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{$\vartriangleleft$}{\textcolor{white}{$\blacktriangleleft$}}}
\tikzcdset{%
    triarrow/.style ={rightarrowtail, "\mytri" {description, inner sep=-2pt}, sloped, allow upside down},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
            A \arrow[r,  triarrow] 
            \arrow[d, triarrow] & 
            B \arrow[dr, triarrow] \\
            C \arrow[ur, triarrow] &
            D \arrow[l, triarrow]
            \arrow[u, triarrow] & 
            E
        \end{tikzcd} 
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]