# Strange behavior of a tikz-cd arrow with description

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd, decorations

While I was answering to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373515/101651), I've found a strange behavior of a `tikz-cd` decoration.

If you observe the image below, you can see that all the triangles are with their tips towards the arrow tail, except for the one on the `C <-- D` arrow (whereas the `description` definition is the same):

[image]

In my answer, I solved the problem with a `xscale=-1`, but I'm wondering if it's a bug or I did something wrong.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\mytri}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{$\vartriangleleft$}{\textcolor{white}{$\blacktriangleleft$}}}
\tikzset{
    triarrow/.style ={"\mytri" {description, inner sep=-1pt}, sloped},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
            A \arrow[r, rightarrowtail, triarrow] 
              \arrow[d, rightarrowtail, triarrow] & 
            B \arrow[dr, rightarrowtail, triarrow] \\
            C \arrow[ur, rightarrowtail,  triarrow] &
            D \arrow[l, rightarrowtail,  triarrow]
              \arrow[u, rightarrowtail,  triarrow] & 
            E
        \end{tikzcd} 
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `sloped` + `allow upside down`. This is Ti*k*Z stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `allow upside down` together with `sloped`.

As the keyname suggests, `sloped` will rotate a `node` so that its baseline is parallel to the tangent line at the attached point to the curve. Usually Ti*k*Z will make a choice between θ and θ+180 so that the readers would not have to twist their necks too hard. On the other hand, `allow upside down` will turn off this mechanism.

Beside that one can use `node`, This is a purely graphical approach

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    triarrow/.style={
        >->,
        postaction={decorate,-},
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position .5 with {
                \arrowreversed{Triangle[fill=white]}
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
            A \rar[triarrow] 
              \dar[triarrow] & 
            B \drar[triarrow] \\
            C \urar[triarrow] &
            D \lar[triarrow]
              \uar[triarrow] & 
            E
        \end{tikzcd} 
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]